# PDO query works from CLI, not from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query which works from the command line, but not from PHP.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
$sqlText = 'SELECT FROM customers WHERE login_name=:name 
                                  AND password=:password';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sqlText);
$query->bindParam(':name', $userName);
$query->bindParam(':password', sha1($password));
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and `$result` is `false`.

But, from the command line,

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE login_name="a" 
                        AND password="4192dee2f886e99ececbb2eee0d2f37f11257974"
```

works.

When I debug `userName` is `a` and `$password` is `4192dee2f886e99ececbb2eee0d2f37f11257974`.

Can some one make me say D'oh ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `execute()`.

Moreover, if really `` $password` is `4192dee2f886e99ececbb2eee0d2f37f11257974 ``, then you must be running sha1() twice. Either remove the sha1() from the bind line, or keep $password in the clear.

I'd suggest naming the database column "passwordHash", and the variable either $password if it is in cleartext, or $passwordHash if you already ran sha1() on it. That way, you would have written

```
$query->bindParam(':passwordHash', sha1($passwordHash));
```

and immediately spotted the extra sha1() call.

Answer (score 5):

You've forgotten about [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-examples) I suppose:

```
$sqlText = 'SELECT FROM customers WHERE login_name=:name AND password=:password';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sqlText);
$hash = sha1($password);
$query->bindParam(':name', $userName);
$query->bindParam(':password', $hash);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: **D'oh!** :DDDDDDDD

Comment: I don't think that's going to work still. `bindParam` needs a variable reference. Either save the `sha1($password)` result into a variable used in `bindParam` or use `bindValue` instead

Answer (score 2):

you have to call `$query->execute();` to execute the query in PDO

```
$sqlText = 'SELECT FROM customers WHERE login_name=:name AND password=:password';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sqlText);
$query->bindParam(':name', $userName);
$query->bindParam(':password', sha1($password));

$query->execute();

$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

The prepare method only prepares the sql statement you passed in and returns a preparedstatement object.

As mentioned above, you need to set the params and execute it to get the resultset back.

The advantages of prepared statement besides the security is that you can repeatedly assign parameters and execute a preparedstatement which is considered to be faster than compiling the same sql query string again and again.